# How to use springfox in a less invasive way?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, springfox, api-doc

I want to use `springfox` to generate API docs in a `springmvc` project. But by using `springfox`, I must add java annotation to controllers and models, which is very invasive. So what can I do to use it in a less invasive way? Or what else frameworks can do it? (I don't know if I can express it clearly.)

Answer (score 0):

Springfox does not require annotations on controllers and model other than those you'd need anyways i.e. spring annotations like `@RequestMapping` or jackson annotations like `@JsonProperty`.

This is explicitly stated as one of the goals of the [springfox project](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#goals)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.And is there any way to report the difference between two version?

Comment: Two versions of what? If u mean with or without the swagger annotations then, you'll most likely miss things like a higher fidelity of expressing things like descriptions, ordering, names. Basically things that help in making the docs better that what is __inferred__.